# Using Chrome, IE, Firefox browsers Maven dependencies for Maven project

Tags: maven, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am new to maven framework. Trying to use various drivers for project. My questions are

1.In my current(without Maven framework), I downloaded all driver.exe files and provided path. I know Maven only handles jar &
    Not Exe. And i saw browsers dependencies on Maven website so how
    browsers.jar will be used for Maven project(for ex Chrome or IE).

2.What should we use System.setProperty( ,"Path") Path for IE, Chrome & GeckoDriver.

3.Also I want to use IE 32bit dependency so how can i find IE 32bit Maven dependency.

4.I dont find Gecko Dependency and I found firefox dependency which has version series 3.4, 3.2, etc but my current Gecko driver without
    maven is 0.15.0 so not sure how to correlate maven firefox dependecy
    similar to my current GeckoDriver version.

Please help. Thanks for your time & effort.

Answer (score 0):

This is what my understanding is, might not be entiery correct.

1. Jar files are platform interdependent, so you don't have to worry about 32 bit or 64 bit operating system, it's same for linux as well. All you have to check is which version of geckodriver you download. as it's native executable.
2. yes, in `System.setProperty( ,"Path")` you should use the path for IE and Chrome, and if you want to use firefox then Geckodriver.exe. you are not going to use all at the same time so read browser name from property file or testng.xml file and based on that create the browser object. 
   for example to set chrome driver binary path. you need to write this.

   **System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/path/to/chromdriver");**
3. You don't need to put the geckodriver.exe in dependancy, as you mentioned earlier it's a executable (.exe) and jar file. it just has to be in PATH variable or set using `System.setProperty`

Comment: Thanks but still i am confused. Could you please post how to start browser in Maven project please

Comment: what do you mean by start browser in maven project. you start browser using selenium and not maven. Maven is build tool, it's going to help you compile, test, build, package and execute your project.

Comment: ok Thanks for response. Starting browser is with selenium but when we write WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver. We need to download ChromeDriver.exe and there are many dependencies available for ChromeDriver. so once we add ChromeDriver. how to write System.setProperty ?